# Difference between push myVar , push [myVar] and push OFFSET myVar

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, masm

I am new to assembly and I'm using MASM.
I see these lines of code and wonder what's the difference between

```
a) push myVar

b) push [myVar]

c) push OFFSET myVar
```

How do I know if they are pushing  the value or the address of myVar
Thanks!

Best regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`push myVar` is simply pushing your var on the stack.

`push [myVar]` is dereferencing your var. if myVar is a pointer, this code will push the value at the address on the stack.

I'm not sure for the last one, but it seems it does the inverse, `push OFFSET myVar` is pushing the address of `myVar` on the stack.

Comment: _"if myVar is a pointer, this code will push the value at the address on the stack."_ Actually it will do exactly the same thing as the first case (push the value of `myVar`).

Comment: Ok. So it means [] doesn't matter. Right?

Comment: No. "push [var] — push the 4 bytes at address var onto the stack" . It means that if var is not a pointer, it could result in an undefined behavior.

Comment: When would a declared variable not have a valid address?

Comment: A useful way to look at it is to convert these expressions into C syntax. So, `[myVar]` is `*myVar` (if it is indeed a pointer) and `OFFSET myVar` is `&myVar`.

Comment: The answer is not clear and the answer of Michael is a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which assembler you use. With MASM/TASM the first two variants do the same thing  (push the value of `myVar` onto the stack), while the third variant pushes the address of `myVar` onto the stack (in segmented mode that would be the offset within the current segment).

In other words, MASM/TASM assumes that you want to dereference the effective address of a variable even if you write it without brackets. If you had an immediate value as the address/operand there would be a difference though:

```
pushd 0             ; push the dword value 0 onto the stack
push dword ptr [0]  ; push the dword at address 0 onto the stack
                    ; will likely crash your program
```

And similary for register operands:

```
push eax              ; push the value of eax onto the stack
push dword ptr [eax]  ; push the value at the address that eax points to
```

---

With NASM you'd write the first two variants as

```
push dword [myVar]  ; assuming a dword variable
```

And the third as

```
push myVar
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have our `data` segment declared like this:

```
.data
myVar DWORD 1, 5, 9
```

**Without [ ]**

Now let's put this in the `code` section:

```
.code
mov eax, myVar
```

If we now take a look at the registers (through a debugger, for example), we can see something like this:

```
EAX = 00000001
```

**With [ ]**

We can use the brackets as a dereference operator like we would use `*` in C, so if we now change the line to this:

```
mov eax, [myVar]
```

we get:

```
EAX = 00000001
```

hmm...the same.

But now we can think, ha!, if a put an address offset to `myVar`, I should obtain the next value from myVar "array":

```
mov eax, [myVar + 4] ; +4, because we have a DWORD (4 Bytes)
```

and the result is:

```
EAX = 00000005
```

It works! But what if I do the same thing without the brackets?

```
mov eax, myVar + 4
EAX = 00000005
```

Hmmh, same thing! So there must be no difference in using the two notations. So they are perfectly equivalent.